# Transaction failed

Tags: transactions, tezbox

I have just created two wallets on TezBox and Cortez (Both on Android mobile). I have sent 1 XTZ to TezBox (using another Cortez wallet) which went through successfully. Later I tried to send from TezBox to newly created Cortez wallet but my transaction is coming as 'fail'. Could anyone ELI5 why is this happening? Here is the wallet address where you can look up the transactions:

https://tzscan.io/tz1WhcpMyCpKUn5J6LNHZoL8bWAQ3uJrbL4j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after some research I found out why the transactions were failing.

To 'activate/reveal' newly created address you need to pay a fee to broadcast it to the blockchain. TezBox wallet was unable to add this extra 'fee' with the transaction thus it was getting ***proto.003-PsddFKi3.storage_exhausted.operation*** error or failing. After reading some similar posts here I proceeded to send a small amount via Cortez and it added the extra fee on top of regular transaction fee and the transaction went through!

Later I transferred the remaining balance from my TezBox wallet and it went through as well.

Sources:

[Link 1](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-can-i-understand-why-a-transaction-has-failed)
[Link 2](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/679/transaction-failing-with-proto-003-psddfki3-storage-exhausted-operation)